# Getting the icon associated with a running application using WinAPI

Tags: winapi

How can I get the icon of a running application provided I know the Hwnd?

Answer (score 6):

If you have the handle to the window, you can use [GetClassLong](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633580%28VS.85%29.aspx):

```
HICON icon = (HICON)GetClassLong(window, GCL_HICON);
```

Comment: This works only for some applications (under Windows 7), like Steam, Firefox, but not for Visual Studio, or Explorer, Skype. You can additionally try to use WM_GETICON, like in this example - http://codeutopia.net/blog/2007/12/18/find-an-applications-icon-with-winapi/ but this still give you only small icons for other. Even if application clearly have bigger icon (as on taskbar), so maybe better way is to get icon from application exe file?

Comment: The link is broken

Answer (score 4):

I you have the hwnd you can get the process ID by using the WINAPI GetWindowThreadProcessId. 
With that you can create a C# Process object. Next, you can iterate through the process' ProcessModule Collection to get the filename of the executable. Finally, you can use the WINAPI function ExtractIconEx to get the icon from the path

Pinvoke has information on the two WINAPI methods

http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/GetWindowThreadProcessId.html

http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/shell32/ExtractIconEx.html